# AngularJs and Bootstrab tiles

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tiles

I am trying to display equal containers with image (that can be submitted with a different size, but resized to a fix size when displayed), and some content (title description, etc) -- similar to the Kickstarter's tiles of projects (https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology?ref=discover_index). I tried columns, tables, container, but looks like I am missing something, because it doesn't want to display equal tiles :(((( HELP!

Here is my last "try"

```
<ul ng-repeat="project in projects" class="col-md-4 col-l-3 col-xl-2"  id="wrap">
<a href="project.html?={{project.objectId}}" id="projectText">
<li><img class="img-responsive" src="{{project.image.url}}"></li>
<li>{{project.title}}</li>
<li>{{project.blurb}}</li>
<li>{{project.likes || 0}}</li>
<li><span id="hover" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementLikes(project, 1)"></span></li>
</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, but I ended up using just bootstrap div  columns.

Answer (score 0):

I did a [quick test](http://www.bootply.com/8wl64sXqbO) and it looks as though you can have col-*-x tags that add up to more than 12, in which case this will work

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="project in projects">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-l-3 col-xl-2">
        <ul>
          <a href="project.html?={{project.objectId}}" id="projectText">
          <li><img class="img-responsive" src="{{project.image.url}}"></li>
          <li>{{project.title}}</li>
          <li>{{project.blurb}}</li>
          <li>{{project.likes || 0}}</li>
         <li><span id="hover" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementLikes(project, 1)"></span></li>
         </a>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```